# Hadoop 3.1.1 issue on start HDFS service

Tags: hadoop, hadoop3

I am configuring Hadoop 3.1.1 on mac. However, once I complete all the steps I got the Permission denied on starting namenode, datanode and secondary namenode.

Also,

> (unable to load native-hadoop library for your plateform.....using builtin-java classes where applicable)

Comment: From which user you're trying to start all these services?

Comment: You can ignore this "unable to load" **warning**, or you can search elsewhere for solutions to it, but no file permissions are needed to run Hadoop by default, so what exactly did you configure it with? It sounds like you are not running a SSH server on your Mac or didn't setup Passwordless SSH correctly.

Comment: @Abhinav i login in my mac as Admin and I am trying to run single node.

Comment: @cricket_007 Java already installed, ssh localhost shows login and no 22 ports issue, password ssh once asked I run it without password, I configured 3 files mapred, hdfs then I formated hdfs namenode

Comment: @Abhinav  thanks and I think the steps to setup hadoop 3.1.1 not same like hadoop 2.6.0 (which available around the net )

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks and I think the steps to setup hadoop 3.1.1 not same like hadoop 2.6.0 (which available around the net )

Comment: Thanks in advance for any support to solve the issue

Comment: Hadoop 3.x changed all of the startup scripts internally, but the process is still mostly the same... And you should start at the official Apache site for the version of Hadoop you are actually using. Besides that, I used Homebrew installed Hadoop a few weeks ago, and it worked fine, but I have root permissions on my Mac

Comment: What i am doing now is just get some of the settings from one stie then others from other site ...... confused , so please Is there any specific site for hadoop 3.1.1 to setup on mac?

Comment: I have successfully installed Hadoop 3.1 on my Windows. But for Mac it looks like this site is a bit helpful https://macmetric.com/how-to-install-hadoop-on-mac/

Answer (score 0):

1. check your  hostname of mac, /etc/hosts and hadoop/etc/hadoop/workers
2. you can find problems in hadoop/logs/hadoop~~datanode~~.log